# Automatically show entry date plus set time

Tags: entry-date

Is there a way to show the date of an entry with an additional set time. ie 90 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not natively within EE's standard tags.

Entry dates are stored as timestamps though so you could use a maths plugin to add on 7776000000 (90 days in milliseconds) then use date formatting to turn that into a nice date.

But that's getting a bit "tag soupy" so you might be better off with a custom plugin that would return the modified, formatted date for you.

Or even more simply, use a plugin that's already out there such as [DT](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/dt-plugin)